# Displaying options for two select

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

friends. Faced such a question. I have two select, in each select of the city they are taken from the database, and in the second select  - the city that is != To the city from the first select. Help me, pleasee..)
Code

```
       <form action="{{route('countDistance')}}" method="post">
    <div class="starter-template">
<select class="selectpicker" name="from" id="from">


@foreach($deps as $depart)
<option>{!!$depart->City!!}</option>
@endforeach
</select>     
<select class="selectpicker" name="to" id="to">


@foreach($deps as $depart)
<option>{!!$depart->City!!}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Count &raquo;</button>
   {{ csrf_field() }}
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Why you want to do this ? you can to display the same object but with results who are not in the first select ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jquery to accomplish this. For that I had to add first option saying 'Please select' for both. On change of #from select box, I hid the option with the same text from #to select box. And before hiding any option, showed all, so that previously hidden option may be available now.

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <form action="{{route('countDistance')}}" method="post">
    <div class="starter-template">
    <select class="selectpicker" name="from" id="from">

    <option>Please select</option>
    @foreach($deps as $depart)
    <option>{!!$depart->City!!}</option>
    @endforeach


    </select>     
    <select class="selectpicker" name="to" id="to">

    <option>Please select</option>
    @foreach($deps as $depart)
    <option>{!!$depart->City!!}</option>
    @endforeach

    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Count &raquo;</button>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    </div>
    </form>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#from").change(function() {
        // first show all from #to
        $("#to > option").each(function() {
            $(this).show();
        });

        console.log($("#from").val());
        var toHide = $("#from").val();
        $("#to option:contains('" + toHide + "')").hide();
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!